# Trouble dealing with next page link

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to get some data from a javascript enabled webpage. There are three things to do before clicking on the next page button because the next page link appears only when the webpage contains the search results. The three things are: filling in two search boxes and clicking on search button. However, my script can do the three things flawlessly but breaks when it is supposed to click on the next page link (throwing timeout exception). As you can see, I've already tried with three different options to click on the next page link but never succeeded. The rest two I tried with are commented out. What to do to click on the next page button successfully?

The script I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://brokercheck.finra.org/")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[placeholder='Name or CRD#']"))).send_keys("Michael John")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[placeholder='Firm Name or CRD# (optional)']"))).send_keys("Morgan Stanley")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.md-button'))).click()
# wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.pagination-next a'))).click()
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.pagination-next a'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.pagination-next a'))).click()
driver.quit()
```

Elements within which next page links are:

```
<ul class="pagination ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" data-ng-if="listCtrl.getTotalResults()" total-items="listCtrl.getDisplayResults()" ng-model="listCtrl.currentPage" max-size="1" page-label="listCtrl.pageLabel($page)" items-per-page="listCtrl.itemsPerPage" ng-change="listCtrl.pageChanged()" boundary-links="true" previous-text="‹" next-text="›" first-text="«" last-text="»" aria-invalid="false">
  <!-- ngIf: ::boundaryLinks --><li ng-if="::boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-first ng-scope disabled"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(1, $event)" class="ng-binding">«</a></li><!-- end ngIf: ::boundaryLinks -->
  <!-- ngIf: ::directionLinks --><li ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-prev ng-scope disabled"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page - 1, $event)" class="ng-binding">‹</a></li><!-- end ngIf: ::directionLinks -->
  <!-- ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index --><li ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active,disabled: ngDisabled&amp;&amp;!page.active}" class="pagination-page ng-scope active"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page.number, $event)" class="ng-binding">1 of 27 pages</a></li><!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
  <!-- ngIf: ::directionLinks --><li ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-next ng-scope"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" class="ng-binding">›</a></li><!-- end ngIf: ::directionLinks -->
  <!-- ngIf: ::boundaryLinks --><li ng-if="::boundaryLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-last ng-scope"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(totalPages, $event)" class="ng-binding">»</a></li><!-- end ngIf: ::boundaryLinks -->
</ul>
```

Comment: can you give the site url

Comment: Sure, it is within the script.

Comment: well there are 2 things, after passing in the keys the url gets changed, so you need to get the current url first, and then then pass this class with a tag and then click

Comment: Did that as well but throws the same exception. Didn't you mean `driver.get(driver.current_url)` and then the rest of my code to click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 paginations on page with the same locators: at the top and at the bottom.

To handle top you need to execute `driver.maximize_window()` to make it visible and then use same code as you tried:

```
link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.pagination-next a')))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', link)
link.click()
```

To handle bottom pagination:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'(//*[contains(@class, "pagination-next")]//a)[2]'))).click()
```

Comment: Get back to you soon sir.

Comment: Tried with the second option but it throws an error: `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (583, 2030)` Can't apply the first solution yet cause i did never use that maximize window command so i don't know how to use that. Giving a search to know a bit.

Comment: `maximize_window()` just allow you to work with browser in "full screen" mode.. This is strange - second works for me also...

Comment: Let me try few more times sir.

Comment: Tried around 15 times but could not get rid of the same error.

Comment: Which element is actually receives the click?

Comment: Is there any way to know: which element receives the click? Forgive my ignorance. Btw, the error is throwing in `line 194, in check_response`.

Comment: Usually error looks like  `Element is not clickable at point (583, 2030) Other element receives the click <div class="...">...</div>`, so you can define that element. Did you try first solution? It seem to be easier solution

Comment: I'm very much willing to go for the first solution as well. I got frightened to see `driver.maximize_window()` command. Now, trying to do that.

Comment: There is nothing frightened in `driver.maximize_window()`:) Moreover, in most cases it should be called in the beginning of test script

Comment: Sir, `link_text` is doing the trick in this case as you have shown me in the other thread. The problem is i needed to scroll the window down to make it work. Ain't there any way to make the window reach the location so that it can click automatically. I tried with `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` but it leads the window at the lowest position from where the location is not visible either.

Comment: Scroll to which location? To the bottom of the page or to element?

Comment: To the element sir, where the sign `>` is located.

Comment: have you tried `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView;', link)`?

Comment: No sir. Trying now.

Comment: Oops. `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', link)` is correct one.. forgot to call the function :)

Comment: Told you earlier that you are invincible. It did the trick. I think you should include this in your answer so that others can take help.

Comment: It seems i put you in a lot of trouble by making questions repeatedly. Thanks for everything sir.

Comment: your provided expression for bottom pagination also worked. I tested it after upgrading my `chromedriver`.